# Enabling jshint for Electron in Brackets

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, electron, jshint, adobe-brackets

Jshint in VS Code does a fantastic job at giving Electron.js related hints:

[image: a screenshot of the auto complete options in Brackets]

But in Brackets (my preferred editor) jshint doesn't give Electron.js specific hints:

[image: and in Visual Studio Code]

Is there a way to fix the lack of hints in Brackets?

Answer (score 0):

This is not jshint. The feature you are looking for is [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) or Code Hints in Brackets terminology.